# Combine query results in same step as query in mongodb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, mongodb, logic

I have 3 mongodb collections that are in the following format:

```
firstCollection = {
     "id":myId,
     "theAssociatedList":myList
}

secondCollection = {
      "id":myId,
      "theAssociatedList":myList
}

thirdCollection = {
      "id":myId,
      "theAssociatedList":myList
}
```

Where you can query each collection by providing an Id, which returns the corresponding list as the result. For example,

After querying all three collections, I receive lists `[A1,A2,...,A3], [B1,B2,...,B3], and [C1,C2,...,C3]` as output. How can I receive `[A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3,...]` in the same step as the query to save runtime? Also, I cannot change the number or format of the collections.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
mongos> db.k1.find()  // collection 1
{ "_id" : ObjectId("601fdf2698e4dc7a4ba5abb4"), "id" : 1, "theAssociatedList" : [ "A1", "A2", "A3" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("601fdf3e98e4dc7a4ba5abb5"), "id" : 2, "theAssociatedList" : [ "A5", "A6", "A7" ] }
mongos> db.k2.find()  // collection 2
{ "_id" : ObjectId("601fdf5198e4dc7a4ba5abb6"), "id" : 1, "theAssociatedList" : [ "B1", "B2", "B3" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("601fdf5e98e4dc7a4ba5abb7"), "id" : 2, "theAssociatedList" : [ "B6", "B7", "B8" ] }
mongos> db.k3.find() // collection 3
{ "_id" : ObjectId("601fdf7498e4dc7a4ba5abb8"), "id" : 1, "theAssociatedList" : [ "C1", "C2", "C3" ] }
mongos> db.k1.aggregate([ 
{$match:{id:1}  },
{ $unionWith:{coll:"k2",pipeline:[ {$match:{id:1}}  ] }},
{ $unionWith:{coll:"k3",pipeline:[ {$match:{id:1}}  ] }},
{$group:{_id:"$id" , a:{ $addToSet:"$theAssociatedList" }}},
{$project:{theAssociatedList:{$reduce:{input:"$a",initialValue:[] , in:{$concatArrays:["$$value" ,"$$this"] } }}}}  ])
{ "_id" : 1, "theAssociatedList" : [ "B1", "B2", "B3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "C1", "C2", "C3" ] }
mongos>
```

explained:

1. Filter id=1 from first collection
2. $unionWith with id=1 from second collection ( $unionWith = SQL UNION ALL )
3. $unionWith with id=1 from third collection
4. $group based on id to form new element a containing all the AssosciatedList's in array
5. $reduce and apply concatArrays to form single array sum of all AssociatedList arrays

Comment: I do not have a corresponding _id, also I believe your syntax is off. There should be quotation marks wrapping at least $match and $unionWith @R2D2